# "How to perform statistical analysis in python on bin file?"

Tags: python

I have a bin file that contains binary values and I converted it into a text file(human readable form).
the code which I have used to convert the bin file to text file:
def main():

```
with open("G:/Dataset/attach-file-1562323491012.bin", "rb") as text_file:
# One option is to call readline() explicitly



# single_line = text_file.readline()

# It is easier to use a for loop to iterate each line
    data1 = text_file.read(10000)

datastring = str(data1)

print(datastring)
print(' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in datastring))

decode(data1)
```

now I want to perform statistical analysis to get the output on this converted text file.
I am not very familiar with Statistical analysis in python.
Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: one of the entries funciton is: `describe`, but in general your question is to broad for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a good look at [Pandas 10 minutes tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).
If it's an one dimensional list, you should start looking at Pandas Series